# How to update sql command from c#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I can't update the user data stored in my database.

I have created a button, and then added the c# code.

Here is my aspx code:

```
  table class="logintable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>

        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                Fornavn
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFornavn" runat="server" />
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Update" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I try with the Update command "Update User" and then " SET Name"

Here is my c# code:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=testingDB;User id=sqluser2;Password=password01;"))
            {

                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Bruger SET Fornavn='" + txtFornavn.Text + "' where Email='"+ Session["Email"] + "';",con);

                //SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand();
                //command1 = con.CreateCommand();

                //command1.CommandText = "UPDATE Bruger set fornavn='"  + txtFornavn.Text+ "' where email='" + Session["email"] + "';";

                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fornavn", txtFornavn.Text);

                command1.Connection.Open();
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();
```

Comment: what is the ask ?

Comment: SQL injection warning by txtFornavn.Text, though it looks like you had a parameter there

Comment: What if my email was `' OR 1=1 --`?

Comment: Ignoring the sql injection issues that have already been mentioned... Can you give us the error or what is happening that you don't expect or what isn't happening that you do expect? "Can't update user data" could mean a lot of things.

Comment: what you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=testingDB;User id=sqluser2;Password=password01;"))
    {
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Bruger SET Name=@Fornavn where Email=@email;",con);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fornavn", txtFornavn.Text);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Session["Email"]);

        command1.Connection.Open();
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: you type too fast; beating me by mere seconds

Comment: You probably want `using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(...` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your SqlCommand should never be constructed with inline variables. This leads to SQL Injection.

As you have not provided the exception that you received, I will have to point out the flaw I did see, which was adding a parameter to the command which had no parameters within it.

My replaement code eliminates the inline variables in the original command, keeping the parameter assignment you did have, and adding a second for the email address.

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Bruger SET Fornavn=@Fornavn where Email=@Email",con);

command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fornavn", txtFornavn.Text);
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FEmail", (string)Session["email"]);

command1.Connection.Open();
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```